# Groovy string integer range

Tags: string, groovy, types

How can use the range operator on string representing integers?

The real problem arise when a string represents an integer bigger than 9. The range will consider the string as a list of numbers, and only use the first one instead of converting the whole string as an integer.

```
String start = '1'
String end = '11'
println "Range over strings"
(start..end).each{println it}
println "Range over integers"
(start.toInteger()..end.toInteger()).each{println it}
```

Result:

> Range over strings
> 1
>
> Range over integers
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10
> 11

I would like to keep the code simple and avoid if possible using too much type conversions since I need the resulting list to contain numbers as string.

Comment: I don't think it's possible w/o type conversion at some point btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do type conversions, maybe a custom range is an idea:

```
class CustomRange extends IntRange {
    CustomRange(String start, String end) {
        super(start.toInteger(), end.toInteger())
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to use this `CustomRange` with `..` operator. How?